# How to make links inside ng-repeat indexable by SEO?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, seo

I have code like this in the root page (e.g. http://www.example.com):

```
<div ng-repeat="url in urls">
   <a ng-href="{{url}}"/>url</a>
</div>
```

Each url is just a SEO-friendly-sub-url (e.g. http://www.example.com/pages/hello-world)

I am aware that Google now executes Javascript (http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.no/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html), but I still can't get those sub-urls being indexed (only the root page is indexed).

How to make it indexable?

If possible, the solution should not depend on third party services such as seo4ajax or prerendex.io

Comment: what if you replace with `ng-href` (which is the proper way to go) ?

Comment: ups, sorry actually it is ng-href. Updating the question

Comment: ...Or is it possible that ng-href is the source of the problem? Google crawler is not smart enough to infer "ng-href" as "href"?

Comment: angular is a huge beast of js, i doubt they can run it. i can see a few ajax loaders here or there, or document.write()-added content, but bootup up a whole angular app? propbably pushing it at this point...  as your link says: "It's always a good idea to have your site degrade gracefully. This will help users enjoy your content even if their browser doesn't have compatible JavaScript implementations. It will also help visitors with JavaScript disabled or off, as well as search engines that can't execute JavaScript yet."

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same problem. I even went so far as to have prerender.io working but from what I can tell the ng-repeat is preventing a successful crawl. ng-href is supposed to be supported.

Comment: It was 6 years ago, not too sure whether I solved it (even if so, Angular has changed a lot since then). However, since then, I worked in React: the way it works is to do server-side-rendering (run React render method on the server side and returns the HTML). I guess there is similar way in Angular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to long but we ran into same issue. We used severals techniques so google can index our website in better way. But honestly saying that that doesn't worked well. We ditched our the front-end framework and decided to go with rails. Now, we are quite happy with `rails tubrolinks`.

This are our few work arounds, may be that will be helpful for you.

1. We first created site map. And, then submitted to google via webmaster tool.
2. When google crawl the website , it sends  something like `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)` as user agent (notice `Googlebot`, thats important). We created one middleware which checks all requests whether they are coming from search engine or not. You can get the list of all such user agents from google (may be http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php will help too). We returned the static page (which essentially contain all data which webpage do but it isnt dynamic).

You might be interested in https://github.com/prerender/prerender_rails

Comment: Good suggestion, but this is a black hat seo technique. Google doesn't respond well to pages that offer different content based on user agent string. So Google may be likely to put your links low in the search results.

Comment: just to tell you this isn't black hat technique and I'm not sending different content. I am just evaluating it before sending them.

Answer (score 1):

You should create server side page for [ajax crawling](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en), managing "_escaped_fragment_" in your rewrite rules.